# Angular 8 : cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I am using Angular material Autocomplete
where I am trying to filter data by entering keyword to textbox
but got error after writing first word only

Code

**ts :**

```js
this.rsControl.valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
    this.rsFiltered = this._filter(newValue);
}


_filter(search: any) {
    returnedVal = this.mocList.filter(result => this._normalizeValue(result.rs_code).includes(filterValue));
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(returnedVal);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}

_normalizeValue(value) {
    if (value) {
        return value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
    }
}
```

**html :**

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]='rsSearch' (keyup)="applyFilter($event , 1)" placeholder="Search RS By Code/Name"
    [formControl]="rsControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" class='searchBox form-control'> <span *ngIf='!rsSearch'
    class="material-icons input-icon">
    search
</span>
<span *ngIf='rsSearch' class="material-icons input-icon" (click)='clear()'>clear</span>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option (click)='selectFilter(data.rs_code)' *ngFor="let data of rsFiltered" [value]="data.rs_name">
        {{data.rs_code}} {{data.rs_name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Your `_normalizeValue(value)` function is returning `undefined`. It looks like one of the values in `this.mocList` is `falsy`, but it's hard to know exactly what's going on with only the code you've provided.

Comment: Result.rs_code is undefined. Also, normalizeValue function must return something even in falsy case.